# How to create horizontally dynamic UICollectionView cells? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hey I'm trying display a set of "tags" in a view controller using collection view cells but I'm having trouble finding a way to make them be able to dynamically resizable depending on the length of the string.

Right now the individual cells are statically sized so whenever a String that populates the cell with characters exceeding the size of the cell, it goes into the second line. I want it so that the cell can change length depending on the length of the String. So if it's the tag "#Vegan", it will automatically resize so that the tag isn't that big. Likewise, if it's a longer string like "#LaptopFriendly", it will become horizontally longer to accommodate the string and not use the second line. The vertical length can stay fixed. Thank you!

[image]

**UPDATE (interface builder settings when I run into errors using Rob's code):**

[image]

Simulator screenshot:
[image]

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: No I'm not sure what code I should write! I'm new to iOS so any help would be appreciated! I would imagine I'd use a collectionView function cellForItemAt??

Comment: It looks like your new screen snapshot it's largely resizing properly. But the one that starts with `#C` is taking two lines. So, two questions: 1. Does your label have `lineCount` set to `1`? If it's set to zero, try setting it to `1`. Also make sure that that value starting with `#C` does not have a newline character in it.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you've added the background color to your label. If you make the label background color clear and apply the background color to the cell, you might get a better look and feel.

Comment: I JUST managed to get it to work. I re added the collection views/cell/labels and it magically worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need unambiguous constraints between your label and the cell (e.g. leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints):

[image]

Then you can use `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` for the `itemSize` of your `collectionViewLayout`. Don't forget to set `estimatedItemSize`, too, which enables automatically resizing cells:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error:

"the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values."

what should I do to fix that? I have some insets so that they don't start at the edge.

Comment: Did you set the `estimatedItemSize`? You get that error if you use `itemSize` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` but neglect to set `estimatedItemSize` to some reasonable estimation to an actual `CGSize` value.

Comment: Yes I did, I have the width set to 150 and I still get errors. My update above shows the screen shot where one of the hashtags still doesn't get dynamically sized. The string is supposed to be "#Couch" but it always crashes before I can get there and loops in errors. Is there something wrong with my label constraints?

Comment: Is `hashtag` is the name of the cell? If so, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your constraints. Or is it a subview of the cell (in which case, we'd then need to see the constraints b/w that subview and the cell)? Maybe it would be easiest if you create a [stand-alone example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem (none of your other code; we don't want to wade through that; just a blank project with a collection view manifesting the problem you describe; it sounds like a hassle, but should only take 10-15 minutes to do). Then upload that somewhere and we can take a look.

Comment: it help me but when i tap on cell then its giving me dynamic width what should i do if i want width dynamic when my app run

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the lengths of the texts ahead of time, feed them into an array accessible by your collectionView and use them them to construct the size of the cell.

```
//Create vars
NSArray * texts = @[@"Short",@"Something Long",@"Something Really Long"];
NSMutableArray * lengths = [NSMutableArray new];
float padding = 30.0f;

//Create dummy label
UILabel * label = [UILabel new];
label.frame = CGRectZero;
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f weight:UIFontWeightBold];

//loop through the texts
for (NSString * string in texts){

    //set text
    label.text = string;

    //calculate length + add padding
    float length = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:label.frame.size
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                            context:nil].size.width + padding;
    //save value into array as NSNumber
    [lengths addObject:@(length)];
}

//drop label
label = nil;
```

Create the size of the cell using some code like this:

```
return CGSizeMake(lengths[indexPath.row], 100.0f);
```

Comment: If you downvote please explain, so I can improve if needed.