# iOS SWIFT application: how to achieve this kind of layout?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to achieve below layout in iOS and should look somewhere close to this.

[image]

Number of blocks/boxes will vary dynamically. And each box will display a static text inside. The boxes should auto-expand or shrink according to the text length.

I am confused how to achieve this. Should I use table view OR collection view?

It will be very useful if someone can give some guidance/heads up to get me started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? 
It looks like you can achieve all this using UIStackView

Comment: A short answer is use a collection view. For guidance probably you should look up some collection view tutorials, such as https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: You can do this with nothing special at all. A label _is_ static text and it _does_ auto-expand or shrink according to text length. So what problem are you actually having?

Comment: `UICollectionView` with standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and `itemSize` of `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` (and any `estimatedItemSize` you want). E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552791/1271826.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with UITableView since it allows data to only be listed as linearly from top to bottom.

Therefore you must go on with UICollectionView. Think of it like a fully customizable UITableView where cells can be listed in either direction and many more customizations can be applied as well.

If you need something to get you started with UICollectionView, [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started) is a starter for you.