# UICollectionView: dynamic cell width for horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with several labels inside located in one line. This collection view has to have horizontal scrolling and cell width calculated dynamically based on the label's sizes.
I found the solution on how to make cell's width dynamic here:
[Dynamic cell width of UICollectionView depending on label width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134986/dynamic-cell-width-of-uicollectionview-depending-on-label-width)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return (labels[indexPath.row] as NSString).size(attributes: nil)
}
```

But this method is only called when the class conforms to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout which has vertical scrolling direction that doesn't suit me.

How can I make dynamic cell width for default layout with horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Found another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552444/how-to-create-horizontally-dynamic-uicollectionview-cells-swift
- works better for me.